# prometheus remote_write metric_relabel_configs does not drop targeted metric

Tags: prometheus, grafana, metrics

I'm monitoring kube-state-metrics pod metrics. I want to filter some of them and not upload to my [Grafana](https://k6.io/docs/) as they are overwhelming.

My *remote_write* configuration (following several guides such as [this](https://valyala.medium.com/how-to-use-relabeling-in-prometheus-and-victoriametrics-8b90fc22c4b2)):

```yaml
remote_write:
- url: https://grafana-host:12345/api/prom/push
  basic_auth:
    username: myself
    password: somePassword
  metric_relabel_configs:
  - source_labels: [__name__,reason]
    regex: "kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason;OOMKilled"
    action: keep
```

When querying the `/metrics` endpoint inside the pod with promethues I can see `kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason` with all of its reasons for example:

`curl localhost:8080/metrics | grep kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason`
yields:

```
 HELP kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason Describes the last reason the container was in terminated state.
# TYPE kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason gauge
kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{...some other labels...,reason="OOMKilled"} 1
kube_pod_container_status_last_terminated_reason{...some other labels...,reason="Completed"} 1
```

But looking at my Grafana, I still see *both* of the metrics being reported and are queryable which I do not expect.

Another question, if possible, is there a way to have an inverse? Keep all that are *not* "OOMKilled" in the reason label?

Answer (score 0):

You have action keep. Use action drop if you want to drop that timeseries.

Comment: this does not address any of my questions